# return higher float value from 2dimensional numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a 2d numpy array, where each entry looks like this:

```
[0.9991291165351868, 0.0008708755485713482]
[9.182693247566931e-06, 0.9999908208847046]
[0.9999074935913086, 9.255139593733475e-05]
```

For each of these entries I would like to return the highest float value, which should look like this:

```
[0.9991291165351868]
[9.182693247566931e-06]
[9.255139593733475e-05]
```

However, when I use the following function:

```
np.max(item)
```

I get this:

```
0.9991291165351868
0.9999908208847046
0.9999074935913086
```

It seems that `np.max()` does not consider 9 larger than 0 - is there an easy fix for this?

Comment: Where is `9` in your array? It's `9e-6` and `9e-5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it correctly and it's working correctly. Both numbers starting with 9 are actually smaller than zero because of the `e-06` and `e-05` at the end. That's the scientific notation to display very small numbers in a compact way (works for large numbers too). You can use this site to convert your numbers and see the actual values: https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/math/scientific-notation-converter.php

For example: 9.182693247566931e-06 = 9.182693247566931 × 10^(-6) = 0.000009182693247566931